# Advice needed, on how to overlay a movie with another object to take its palce

Tags: animation, tracking

[MOD PART}I have my animation all finished now, with the doors opening minus the details in the doors. Using Shape Key Animation[end mod part]

I tried this tracking option before. It was off of a youtube instruction on how to play a movie within a movie.  He used a laptop screen that was turned off. end prouduct was a movie being played on the leptop screen.

I tried it using a cork board. Then learned why he used a turned off laptop screen. I seen that this movies that is being incerted into the orginal movie has transparency issues. Somehow, I forgot how I did this. I just used another plane turned it black then hooked it to my tracking points. Then I rendered that out first, then put that movie into Blender tracked it again, then used the inlayed movie in that newly reRendered / tracked movie to get it to work so that I and others could not see the cork in the corkboard.

Thinking their has to be a eaiser way when one does not have green screen. to get the orginal layer to be covered up while using a layer of whatever over top of it to replace what is really there.

[image]

the doors within this movie are to be the subject that is malnipulated in such a manner that it looks like they are opening and the vision of Jesus entering the room. that is my concept, what method is used to block out the orginal image through out the entire movie, so that this fx by use of blender objects to replace what is already there within the movie can be applied through out the entire movie.? (runtime 00:01:30)

Comment: The two basic ways to replace part of an image with another element are: By placing something on top of the image, by means of an alpha channel (using the alpha over node). Or by cutting a hole on your image via masks to create an alpha channel on the image to reveal an underlaying image or scene. Both techniques can be combined. Look for tutorials on plane tracking and compositing.

Comment: @cegaton I'm checking in to that one 4 sure, Thanks

Comment: Look for Sebastian Koenig's track **match blend 2** series of videos.